# List group with 2 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have this:

```
Featured Ads
Ad 1 | Ad 3
Ad 2 | Ad 4
```

I'm using the latest Bootstrap version but i can't get this working. Here is my bootstrap live example: http://www.bootply.com/VwX8n6sHmM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure each ad only fills 50% of the containers' width:

```
.home-description {
    width: 50%
}
```

Then, assign a class for left and one for right to each add, alternately:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item home-description left">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item home-description right">
(... and so on)
```

Finally, float the ads left and right:

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use bootstrap grids like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Ad 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Ad 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Us2fbvOrfi

For more information: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/